# What number am I ? (square number and triangle number)

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

I'm a square number,
I'm also a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number),
You can write me as the sum of 2 square numbers,
You also can write me as the sum of 2 triangle numbers,
You also can write me as the sum of 1 square number and 1 triangle number,
I'm the smallest number of my kind.

What number am I ?

Bonus Puzzle : Find the second smallest number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> $1225$.

This is a [square triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number), i.e. both a square number and a triangular number. It is also a sum of two squares, since

> $1225=5^27^2$ contains every $(4k+3)$-type prime factor an even number of times. (Explicitly, $1225=21^2+28^2$.)

And a sum of two triangular numbers, since

> $8\times1225+2=9802=2.13^2.29$ contains every $(4k+3)$-type prime factor an even number of times - see [this Maths.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164862/determine-if-a-number-is-the-sum-of-two-triangular-numbers). (Explicitly, $1225=T_{19}+T_{45}$.)

And a sum of one square number and one triangular number:

> $1225 = 136+1089=T_{16}+33^2$.

It's the smallest square triangular number which is a sum of two squares, since $36$ isn't a sum of two squares.

**Bonus round**: the second smallest example is probably

> $41616$. This is the next smallest square triangular number; it's also a sum of two squares, since it's $2^43^217^2$; it's a sum of two triangular numbers since $8*41616+2=2.5.13^2.197$; I haven't verified whether it's the sum of a square number and a triangular number.

Comment: Being congruent to $1$ mod $4$ is not enough for a number to be the sum of two squares. For example $3 \times 7 = 21$ is not the sum of two squares. A number is the sum of two squares iff in its prime factorisation every prime that is $3$ mod $4$ occurs an even number of times.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oops! For some reason I thought the two were equivalent; I should have known better. That's what I get for answering questions at 4am :-)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - That is only true if one defines a sum of two squares to include the case when one of the squares is $0$, giving for example $9$ as the sum of two squares because $9=3^2+0^2$.

Comment: The fourth condition in the question is unnecessary, since all squares greater than 1 are the sum of two consecutive triangular numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the bonus question is that the second smallest number that meets the conditions is

> 1413721.

The

> square triangular numbers run 1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721, ...

and whereas

> 41616 is not the answer, because it is not the sum of a square and a triangle number,

the

> next number is the answer,

because

> $1413721 = 1160^2 + 261^2$ (sum of squares)
> = $1180^2 + T_{206}$ (sum of a square and a triangle number), where $T_{206}$ is the 206th triangle number, $\frac{(206)(207)}{2}=21321$.
> There is no need to check whether it is the sum of two triangle numbers, because all squares greater than 1 are. The stipulation "greater than 1" is required when we use the question author's definition of triangle numbers as positive.